# Warning: mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

Не получается подключится к базе данных
 
Есть два файла, первый:

```
<?php
    const DB_SERVER = 'localhost';
    const DB_USER = 'root';
    const DB_PASSWORD = '';
    const DB_NAME = 'website_users';
    const MAX_LEN = 64;
?>
```

Второй:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)
    or die(mysqli_connect_error());

    $select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME) or die('Cannot select DateBase!');


?>
```

Хотя, если вместо констант поставить непосредственно их значения, тогда проблем не возникает

 mysqli_connect_error() возвращает следующее:
Parse error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: ���� ���� ����������.

Comment: Что возвращает `mysqli_connect_error()`?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>', expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Comment: Не понял. Функция не может такого вернуть. Позакрывайте кавычками свои строки

Comment: Исправьте синтаксическую ошибку и попробуйте снова.

Comment: подправил описание проблемы

Comment: `mysqli_connect_error() ` не возвращает синтаксических ошибок. А во-вторых - как второй файл узнает о первом, вы подключаете его или думаете что и так сойдет?

Comment: понял, подключил файл и все заработало, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо файлы просто не подключены.
Используйте **[include](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php)**

```
config.php
<?php
    const DB_SERVER = 'localhost';
    const DB_USER = 'root';
    const DB_PASSWORD = '';
    const DB_NAME = 'website_users';
    const MAX_LEN = 64;
?>

connect.php
<?php
    include "config.php";
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)
    or die(mysqli_connect_error());

    $select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME) or die('Cannot select DateBase!');
?>
```